# Hide Toolbar and BottomBar in CoordinatorLayout when scrolling - visible under transparent status bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have main activity with `NavigationDrawer` `Toolbar` and `BottomBar`. Inside the activity is container for fragments. And the fragment has `RecyclerView`. So when user is scrolling, I want to hide the `Toolbar` and `BottomBar` accordingly. I did that using layout behavior on recycler `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` and layout scroll flags `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"` on Toolbar. For BottomBar I'm using this library: https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

The problem is, that when the `Toolbar` and `BottomBar` are scrolled off the view, they are still visible under the `StatusBar` and `NavBar`

My code:

STYLE:

```
<style name="TranslucentStatusTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

MAIN ACTIVITY CONTENT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_main_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.activity.MainActivity"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        />

    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_bar_menu_height"
        app:bb_activeTabColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:bb_behavior="shifting|shy|underNavbar"
        app:bb_inActiveTabColor="@color/bottom_bar_inactive_tab_color"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

AND IMAGES OF MY PROBLEM:

When no fitsSystemWindows flag is set - the toolbar is below stauts bar
[image: When no fitsSystemWindows flag is set]

When no fitsSystemWindows flag is set and content is scrolled - the toolbar is hide properly, but the bootom bar is still visible below nav bar
[image: When no fitsSystemWindows flag is set and content is scrolled]

When fitsSystemWindows flag is set to root coordinator - the normal state looks ok
[image: When fitsSystemWindows flag is set to root coordinator]

When fitsSystemWindows flag is set to root coordinator and content is scrolled - the status bar and bottom bare are visible below the transparent status bar and nav bar
[image: When fitsSystemWindows flag is set to root coordinator and content is scrolled]

Can anybody help me what I'm doing wrong? I already tried all possible combinations of fitsSystemWindows on different views.

EDIT:

I fixed the Toolbar below status bar issue, but I don't think that the solution is clean. I'm still looking for better one. And I still cannot solve the bottom bar issue

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);
 }
.....
 // A method to find height of the status bar
 private int getStatusBarHeight() {
      int result = 0;
      int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
      if (resourceId > 0) {
         result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
      }
      return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide BottomBar on scroll, you need to set app:bb_behavior="shy"

```
<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_bar_menu_height"
    app:bb_activeTabColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:bb_behavior="shy"
    app:bb_inActiveTabColor="@color/bottom_bar_inactive_tab_color"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />
```

Comment: I'm already using this behavior for scrolling, but if I use it as it is my my sample `app:bb_behavior="shifting|shy|underNavbar` then there is the problem that I'm describing in my question and images.

Comment: I just used app:bb_behavior="shy", instead of "shifting|shy|underNavbar" and for me bottom bar, is not visible under nav bar. Check running the app and code at  https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar. Button "Three tabs with quick return".

Comment: It is not visible below the NavBar because your `Navigation Bar` is not transparent. As you can see in my images, I have transparent `Navigation Bar` and because of that I have to set the `underNavbar` behavior. In the samples from the repository, there is not such sample with combination of `shy` and `underNavbar`. But if I look into the Material Design guidelines, there is recommended to have transparent `Navigation Bar` for more content on the screen: https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior